# How can Resistance be transferred across in a Transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image]

Can someone tell me how the resistor could be transfered from the secondary to the primary side? Could you give me a concise explanation on how it's possible? A simple analogy/analysis would be very hepful.

Comment: Do you have a link for the diagram and the text that went with it?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tell me how the resistor could be transfered from the secondary to the primary side? Could you give me a concise explanation on how it's possible?

This is conceptually similar to how you can combine parallel or serial resistances to get a new equivalent resistance. When you do that you are not saying that the resistors actually merge, you are just saying that you don’t care about the details between the two resistors, you just want the overall effect on the rest of the circuit.

In this circuit there is a resistance between the source and the transformer and another resistance between the transformer and the load. If we don’t care about where the energy is lost, then we can use this transformation to get an overall “effective resistance” that can describe the overall total loss in one single number.

Comment: So you could actually use the manual 'long' way to find the required values without combining these resistors, but it would just waste time and make things more complicated, right?

Comment: Yes, although for some purposes the long way may be necessary. For example if you needed to do a cost analysis of reducing the resistance and the cost of reducing the resistance was different on the source vs load side.